# If ASCII String Contains Letter or Number, Then Return Text

Tags: c#, string, search, ascii

Still working on my project, and would like some more help. Here's my problem: I have a string of chars in `CompanyID` that may be full of " " spaces (derived from ASCII hex text). Some code I've tried won't detect the spaces (possibly because there's many hex characters that return spaces with different values), and the code (FIG B.) returns a value of all spaces. What I would like to do is search the string 'CompanyID' for any Letter/Number. If true, I need `textBox10.Text = CompanyID;` If not, I need to have output to a textbox as shown in Fig, A.

FIG. A:

```
else textBox10.Text = "No Value!";
if (val.Contains("No Value!")) textBox10.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
```

FIG. B:

```
// COMPANY ID
{
BinaryReader br3 = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(OpenFileDialog1.FileName));
                br3.BaseStream.Position = 0x110;
                Char[] charArray = br3.ReadChars(16);
                string CompanyID = new string(charArray);
                textBox10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                textBox10.Text = CompanyID;
                br3.Close();
                {
                    // CODE REPLACEMENT
                    string val = CompanyID;
                    textBox10.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    foreach (char c in CompanyID)
                    {
                        if (Char.IsDigit(c)) textBox10.Text = CompanyID;
                        else textBox10.Text = "No Value!";
                        if (val.Contains("No Value!")) textBox10.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    }
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: "return spaces with different values"—should tell you that you aren't using ASCII. So, is "ASCII hex text" also not ASCII? Are you handling that properly? Hex characters are used to represent bytes. Bytes represent encoded text. There is no text but encoded text. You have defaulted to the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set at [`new BinaryReader(…)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k01zeat(v=vs.110).aspx). (This could very well be correct, especially since ASCII hasn't been generally used for text files in the last 3 decades.)  [I don't see where hex is involved, though.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to solve my problem. Someone suggested using `IsWhiteSapce` to detect if there was anything in a string (even tho the post got somehow deleted), and its been working for me. Thanks for the peeps who replied.

```
// DESCRIPTION
            {
                BinaryReader br7 = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(OpenFileDialog1.FileName));
                br7.BaseStream.Position = 0x1c8;
                Char[] charArray = br7.ReadChars(40);
                string Desc = new string(charArray);
                textBox11.Text = Desc;
                if (textBox11.Text.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
                {
                    textBox11.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    textBox11.Text = "No Value!";
                }
                else textBox11.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                br7.Close();
```